How to get current linked lane count of a USB 3.2 Gen 2x2(20Gb/s) device using Windows APIs
I can get USB 3.2 Gen 2(10Gb/s) current linked one lane information from DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedPlusOrHigher using IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2.
How can I get current linked lane count of a USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 device using Windows APIs?

So far the answer is "no, there is no way to request this information".
But Windows 11 Build 26100 comes with the new DeviceIoControl call IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION which fills a USB_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION struct.
A handle to the USB device's hub is required, inputs are the ConnectionIndex (aka port number) and the struct size.
Most of the output values are always the same, the only variants are RxLaneCount and TxLaneCount which are either 0 for 1 lane and 1 for 2 lanes.
IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION
USB_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION sspi = {
    nPort, sizeof(USB_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION)
};

DWORD dwBytesReturned;
int res = DeviceIoControl(hHub,
                          IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_SUPERSPEEDPLUS_INFORMATION,
                          &sspi, sizeof(sspi),
                          &sspi, sizeof(sspi),
                          &dwBytesReturned, NULL);

How to open the hub and determine the port number I have shown here:
How-to-Restart-a-USB-Port
Here is what UsbTreeView V4.4 makes of it:
            -------- Connection SuperSpeedPlus Information --------
Length                   : 0x18 (24 bytes)
Connection Index         : 0x03 (3)
Rx.SublinkSpeedAttrID    : 0x01 (ID 1)
Rx.LaneSpeedExponent     : 0x03 (Lane Speed Exponent is 9 -> Gbit/s)
Rx.SublinkTypeMode       : 0x00 (Symmetric)
Rx.SublinkTypeDir        : 0x00 (Receive Mode)
Rx.Reserved              : 0x00
Rx.LinkProtocol          : 0x01 (SuperSpeedPlus)
Rx.LaneSpeedMantissa     : 0x000A (Lane Speed Mantissa is 10)
Rx.LaneCount             : 0x00 (1 Lane)
Tx.SublinkSpeedAttrID    : 0x01 (ID 1)
Tx.LaneSpeedExponent     : 0x03 (Lane Speed Exponent is 9 -> Gbit/s)
Tx.SublinkTypeMode       : 0x00 (Symmetric)
Tx.SublinkTypeDir        : 0x01 (Transmit Mode)
Tx.Reserved              : 0x00
Tx.LinkProtocol          : 0x01 (SuperSpeedPlus)
Tx.LaneSpeedMantissa     : 0x000A (Lane Speed Mantissa is 10)
Tx.LaneCount             : 0x00 (1 Lane)
-> Rx speed is 10 Gbps
-> Tx speed is 10 Gbps

Unfortunately Microsoft did not update the USB port capability reporting, the USB_PROTOCOLS enum ends at "Usb300", so there is still no way to determine if a port supports more than  SuperSpeed by API.
